# Add a value in http request in Gatling

Tags: gatling

I am using http request in Gatling as
.get(“http://Gatling.com/messages/“).
I need to add a param in the URL which will be picked from the variable ${Correlation}
So my URL should look like this
.get(“http://gatling.com/message/${CorrelationID}) I need to pass in from in my URL
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For fill variable use `feed`. There is official documentation [Feeders](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/feeder/)

At first let's define feed variable:

```
val idFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("CorrelationID" -> "some value"))
```

And add to scenario with request:

```
scenarion(...)
.feed(idFeeder)
.exec(....)
```